# Reducing heavy scanned PDF(keeping only OCR and removing scanned image)

Tags: pdf, conversion

I have an heavy scanned pdf with OCR. I was able to reduce its size by half with [ghostscript win64](https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html), with this command (as recommended in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/256449/473020)):

```
gswin64 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```

But still it's not light enough.

I could also convert the pdf with [Calibre](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/#customizing-calibre-s-e-book-conversion) or [pdftotext from xpdf](https://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html) but I am loosing the layout.

Is there a way to extract the OCR keeping the exact position of each text on each page while removing the scanned image?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [ocrmypdf](https://ocrmypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) with [JBIG2](https://ocrmypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jbig2.html)?

```
ocrmypdf --optimize 3 --jbig2-lossy in.pdf out.pdf
```